Debugging threadvar values
I recently changed some global var declarations to threadvar, but the Evaluate/Modify window now gives 'Inaccessible value' for these at a breakpoint.
I thought I would get the instance value for the current thread, but no.
Is there a way to inspect the value other than modifying the code and assigning its value to a temporary local variable?

The IDE/debugger runs in an entirely different process from the application under test. If they wanted to, they could let the debugger have access to the threadvar variables as the memory for those can be accessed indirectly via the thread information block, but it would require special logic in the debugger, not just to access the values but also to present them correctly as the debug operator switches between threads.

Not sure if it can handle it, but the Parnassus Parallel Debugger (found in GetIt) just maybe could help?
